# How can I make "factors of linear factors and quadratic factors" less redundant?

Tags: word-problem

This could have been easily been a two second question and answer in the chat but apparently I need to clog the questions section first.
All I'm trying to do is express $$(ax+b)(ax^{2}+bx+c)$$ in a conventional generalized way. Clearly "factors of linear factors and quadratic factors" is highly redundant, but what else could you possibly call a factor that is also always in the form of a linear expression or a quadratic expression?

Comment: How about *product* of linear and quadratic factors?

Comment: Your expression is the product of polynomials of **degree at most 2**.

Comment: First one is better, I'll go with that, thanks.